# Page.Culture vs Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webforms, asp.net-webpages

I have been using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` with `System.Threading` and `System.Globalization`, for a while now to manually set the language used by my ASP.net pages, mainly WebForms and WebPages with Razor.

See [MSDN: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I recently read a tutorial that was using `Page.UICulture` instead (actually, `UICulture` which appears to be strongly typed). To my surprise I ended up with exactly the same result; they both changed my websites' ui language settings and read the correct resource file.

See [MSDN: Page.UICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.uiculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To me, the `Thread.CurrentUICulture` makes more sense (I say that intuitively, since it's literally "changing the culture of the current thread").

But calling Page.Culture is much easier and doesn't require to call yet another pair of ASP.net `using`, so I've settled for that solution for now.

Is there a fundamental difference between the two or are they perfectly interchangeable ?

The reason why I worry is that I have a bunch of old websites developed with the first method and I am afraid to run into interchangeability conflicts if I update them to the second one rashly.

**Note**: I usually focus on `UICulture` in my line of work and `Culture` is very accessory to what I do, but I am asking the question for the both of them.

Comment: Can you please clarify what property you are talking about - link to MSDN would be the best... I.e. [System.Web.UI.Page.UICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.page.uiculture%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) marked as "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."... (if you are talking about this one that MSDN have exact explanation too - "This property is a shortcut for the CurrentThread property")

Comment: I read that. But I do not understand the "is not intended to be used directly from your code". Also, CurrentUICulture is a CultureInfo object whereas UICulture is a simple String object. How come? Are they really interchangeable ?

Comment: Note that UICulture will not work when doing async stuff that may execute on another thread. You need to pass such information to the methods that uses them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page.UICulture` is a wrapper around `Thread.CurrentThread` property and is ment for internal .NET framework use:

> This property is a shortcut for the CurrentThread property. The culture is a property of the executing thread
>
> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Looking at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Page.cs,a46944788fe05027), you can clearly see that:

```
public string UICulture 
{
    set 
    {
        CultureInfo newUICulture = null;

        if(StringUtil.EqualsIgnoreCase(value, HttpApplication.AutoCulture))
        {
            CultureInfo browserCulture = CultureFromUserLanguages(false);
            if(browserCulture != null) 
            {
                newUICulture = browserCulture;
            }
        }
        else if(StringUtil.StringStartsWithIgnoreCase(value, HttpApplication.AutoCulture)) 
        {
            CultureInfo browserCulture = CultureFromUserLanguages(false);
            if(browserCulture != null) 
            {
                newUICulture = browserCulture;
            }
            else
            {
                try 
                {
                    newUICulture = HttpServerUtility.CreateReadOnlyCultureInfo(value.Substring(5));
                }
                catch {}
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newUICulture = HttpServerUtility.CreateReadOnlyCultureInfo(value);
        }

        if (newUICulture != null) 
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newUICulture;
            _dynamicUICulture = newUICulture;
        }
    }
    get { return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They do *exactly* the same thing.

As you can see on the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.page.uiculture(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This property is a shortcut for the CurrentThread property. The culture is a property of the executing thread

Comment: Thanks. But CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture are CultureInfo objects. Page.UICulture and Page.Culture are String objects. Are they still interchangeable regardless ? Am I not going to run into an error from using both in the same code ?